# Jackson Object to Json

Tags: java, jackson

I am using following code to map Java entities into JSON

```
public String mapToJson(AbstractEntity obj) throws JsonProcessingException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    System.out.print(mapper.writeValueAsString(obj));
    return mapper.writeValueAsString(obj);
}
```

AbstractEntity is Parent class, when I use this function I am getting output

```
{"className":"com.mycompany.Class1","id":null,"name":"test", "description":"test"}
```

whereas I am expecting

```
{"id":null,"name":"test","description":"test"}
```

with out className.

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = As.EXISTING_PROPERTY, property = "className" )
Abstract Entity
 public abstract class AbstractEntity {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
@Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
private Long id;
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
}
```

Class1

```
 public class Class1 extends AbstractEntity implements Serializable {
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "description", nullable = false)
    private String description;
 }
```

Calling :

```
 Class1 obj1= new Class1 ();
    obj1.setClassName("test");
    obj1.setDesciption("test");
   mapToJson(obj1);
```

Comment: What is `AbstractEntity`?

Comment: its superclass with some common attributes.  Class1 extends AbstractEntity

Comment: Please add the (relevant) definitions to your question.  It's likely impossible to say what the issue is without seeing some code.

Comment: Can you clarify what `attr1` is, and what happened to `name` and `description`?

Comment: from where `"attr1"` come from?

Comment: Basically, something doesn't add up here.  Usually this (a type field) is a symptom of using `@JsonTypeInfo`, but that's not present here.  But you're also not showing us code that corresponds to the output, so I'm not convinced we're seeing the full picture here ;)

Comment: sorry about that , I have updated my post with more details

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth  Thanks for your comment, I have totally ignored  `@JsonTypeInfo`. Adding `visible=false` fixed my problem.